# pyspark asynchronous return from worker machines

Tags: python, asynchronous, apache-spark, distributed-computing, pyspark

I am running a python application using PySpark. The code partitions a RDD using RDD.parallelize() method. Then I send the data partitions to different worker nodes and each worker nodes run a function which update some parameters using the data partition. Finally, I collect the updated values of parameters from all the worker machines using .collect() method. Since different machines have different computation speeds, different machines finish the computation in different times. So, I want to return the updated parameter from the machines as soon as they are finished and collect it in master machine in an asynchronous way as opposed to the usual .collect() method which does it in synchronous way (returning values after all machines have finished computation). Is there any such function pyspark specific to do this task?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think Spark's execution model support this. All operations in a job are grouped into stages demarcated by any shuffling/repartitioning that goes on between them. Within the execution DAG that is built, a stage must wait for its parent stage to finish before beginning execution. Because any sort of operation that returns data to the driver (e.g. `collect()`, `take()`, `first()`) will be in placed in a separate stage, you cannot asynchronously start moving data before the parent stage finishes.

Comment: Hi Rohan, thanks for your reply. It seems that this is not allowed in spark execution model. Do you know if we can save the result for each partition immediately to some shared file system from worker or to local storage in master machine?

Comment: I think the normal `saveAs*` commands should suffice as they don't require shuffling. However, depending on the output committer you use, the entire task might need to finish before output is committed to the final location on your shared file system (as you could run into some weird issues with speculative execution). You could set your own direct-to-output output committer and get around this but it's not recommended. (See [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10063) for an example where it causes issues.

Comment: Hi Rohan, thanks for the insights. But if we have an iterative operation inside the function called inside rdd.foreachPartition(function). And if inside the function the first step is to read a variable from file, update the variable using content of that partition and then again save it in the shared file system. And this process is done for several iteration. I guess in this situation the committer will not sync each iterations? what do you think?